# Using ASP.NET Resources in React

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, localization

I have an old MVC 4 project that uses ASP.NET Resources in Razor views for localization.

I.e in a Razor view you may see

> Views/Register.cshtml:

```
@Resource(() => Local.TermsAndConditions
```

This will go off and fine

> Resources/Register.resx

And find the 'TermsAndConditions' parameter with the correct culture.

Now I don't actually know how all of this works, I've never worked on a multi-lingual application before, but I know that these resx files don't even have the correct information - what actually happens is somehow we fetch these from what looks like a complicated set of SQL tables in the database, using a built ResourceCache class.

I am trying to re-write the front-end using React, but am struggling with how to keep the localization - there are hundreds of entries and I am pulling my hair out a little here.

The only solution I can think of, is to manually find all the keys that would be required to lookup at the top of the view, and send these off to a custom API that will process these values for me, but feel like that may cause a large overhead on my application!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I solved this by creating a simple API method

```
List<string, string> LocaliseStrings (List<string> keys)
{
   // get UI culture
   // look up translated string
   // add to return list in KVP
}
```

This would be called on every front-end page before anything else, and return the strings necessary